# AngularJs drag & drop GUI builder & code generator

Tags: gratis, angularjs, rad

Is there something like [Bootstrap studio](https://bootstrapstudio.io) for AngualarJS?

Something which will present me with a palette for HTML components and let me drag & drop them to create a web page while auto-generating the accompanying AngularJs code? (like Delphi & Visual Basic)

---

[Update] I found [this list](http://bootstrapbay.com/blog/bootstrap-editors/) of GUI editors *for the Twitter bootstrap*. And some discussion of whether the Twitter bootstrap [can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421707/best-way-to-combine-angularjs-and-twitter-bootstrap)/should be used with AngularJs. And even an Angular implementation, [Angular Strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/).

I have signed up for [this](http://ionicframework.com/blog/ionic-creator/), which looks extremely promising, but is still 6 months or more away.

I am still unaware of how best to proceed, but will update the question (and answer) further as I research.

Comment: Sigh! One thousand views and no answer; not even a comment. I guess there aren't many AngularJS gurus active on this site :-(

Comment: What is it you're thinking of when you say "the accompanying AngularJS code"? If you want to use AngularJS, what is it you want the GUI RAD tool to do?

Comment: Let me lay out the GUI, then generate skeleton "OnClick", "OnChange", etc , handlers for me to code. I guess I am too used to Delphi :-/

Comment: Could you please fix the Bootstrap studio link? Thanks :-)

Comment: Out of curiosity, any updates to this? Ionic Creator has launched but it doesn't let users map data sources to the UI which is something I am hoping to do

Comment: Sorry, I only saw this 3 years after you asked. No, I never found a solution. And I have since moved on to Angular, rather than AngularJs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend **[WaveMaker](https://www.wavemaker.com)**

*Initially* you will think the java spring framework @ the back end will be first class citizen only, but when you get your hands dirty with this RAD tool, you will know that all the front-end logic, is written in Angular. Every entity in the back end is linked to $scope variables , angular expressions in the front-end etc. I did an application that consumed only rest services from Nodejs express also.

On the other hand, if you are a java developer and an expert in the Angular js, and know xml, then another excellent framework to build LOB Apps is [Axelor](http://www.axelor.com/), opensource of course.

Comment: Just to update on it. I have just found Allcount JS , it is now integrated with ionic framework to build mobile ready apps. All Count JS is a framework where you specify your dictionary, layout and behavior using only JSON configuration style.

Comment: https://allcountjs.com/ says that it works with AngularJs- yay!!

Comment: $500/month ... ouch

Answer (score 0):

[RADKick](http://RADKick.com) allows you to design Bootstrap components, AngularJS, Knockout, Kick.js and Flutter. I am using this for our internal projects.

Comment: "I am using this for our internal projects" you also appear to be associated with the company. We prefer you indicate that when posting. Btw, you will get more enquiries if you give pricing on your web site than if you don't.

Comment: While this isn't SPAM per se, requiring the visitor to contact developer, especially in these modern times, to obtain more information is questionable.

Comment: The web site says copyright 2016 to 2018, despite this being answered in 2019 :-)