# Drag and drop tool used for portlets of varying size?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to develop a portal with numerous portlets.  The dimensions of each portlet can vary.  Something like this:

[image]

I'm looking for a tool (JS library) that would allow for this type of functionality.  I was unable to find anything helpful from preliminary searching.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I really, really want this too. BUT, don't hold your breath (is this in any way similar to my long unanswered question? http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16649/angularjs-drag-drop-gui-builder-code-generator)

Comment: @Mawg: http://gridster.net/#demos Thoughts? And looks like there's an Angular port: https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster

Comment: Oops, I missed this comment, way back then. For me, I wanted drag & drop., For you, what's wrong with CSS grid?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend 'LMDD' drag and drop script.
Its positioning algorithm can handle this type of layout easily.
Examples here:
https://supraniti.github.io/Lean-Mean-Drag-and-Drop/