# Is there a website builder for generating responsive ui for angular applications

Tags: html, gui-builder, bootstrap, responsive-design, angular

See question at the bottom, and info about the question just below.

In our company we have an internal website which we built using AngularJS (V1.X) around 4-5 years ago. We think it is time for an upgrade as we have a bunch of new ideas and maintaining and developing this site is.. cumbersome at least.

In the time we have been "away" it seems that a lot of stuff has happened with React and Vue getting a lot of traction, but we would still like to use Angular (or at least JavaScript/TypeScript) as we are familiar with it.

The main struggle we had with the last site was actually getting the UI to look nice and especially to make it responsive (phone/tablet/pc). We did this (as well as we could) using bootstrap V2, but it was a very tedious task as we are not strong designers and not very educated in CSS. That is why we would like to find some "tool" that helps us build the UI part but gives us the freedom of maintaining the backed ourselves which leads us to the question:

**Question**:
Do any "tools/websites" exist that lets you design your UI (like a website builder) while giving you the opportunity to "hook" into the code and control all the data and actions yourself?

Comment: Welcome aboard. This sounds quite like [my question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16649/angularjs-drag-drop-gui-builder-code-generator), so take a look there